# Preparing HTML Form Input for SQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently testing a html form which sends the data through php to the sql database. The problem I'm facing is special characters break the form and don't update the database. I haven't tested all the special characters but mainly `` ` `` and `'` are the culprits. I've tried mysql_escape_string, preg_replace and add_slashes with no success. What am I missing?

```
$description = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\ %&$=+*?()!.-]/', ' ', $_POST['description']);
$description = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/"," ",$description);

// Items Insert
foreach ($item as $index=>$value) {
$sqlItems .= "
    INSERT INTO quote_items (quote_id, item, description, amount, gst)
    VALUES ('$last_id', '$item[$index]', '$description[$index]', '$amount[$index]', '$gst[$index]');
";
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mate, always include code and results in your question! This way we can't guess which code your using.

Comment: Sorry I'll add it now, I was assuming there was a standard php function I was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this (a little dirty) but it should allow those 2 characters to be saved

```
$sqlItems .= '
    INSERT INTO `quote_items` (quote_id, item, description, amount, gst)
    VALUES ("'.$last_id.'", "'.$item[$index].'", "'.$description[$index].'", "'.$amount[$index].'", "'.$gst[$index].'");
';
```

EDIT: sorry had the quotes reversed

Comment: Hi DevFx, Thank you, that's worked for those two characters. What exactly does that do and why is it dirty? I can now use '`-={}|[]\:";'<>?,./ symbols without the form breaking. I've tested the form with random combinations of symbols. I can't see a pattern as to why the form is breaking on some symbols and not others. 
f~ saves
f~! saves
f~!@ saves
f~!@# does not save
f~!@#$ does not save
f~!@#$% does not save
##asdf#asdf saves
@#$ saves

Comment: Hi Azyrus I only call it dirty because i would prefer PDO or some type of framework. Please refer to php.net [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

Can you post you DB call?
Those two characters in particular look like they would conflict in a DB call.

The ` is usually wrapped a table or column name
and the ' is usually wrapped around values.

Both of these would cause a problem but without code its hard to say

Comment: Hi DevFX, I've edited now. I assumed there was a php function that was standard. Thanks.

Comment: ok first the single quote ' in your values will break because it becomes the end quote for each value and your DB call becomes jumbled